# Create a temp file with a specific extension using php

Tags: php, temporary-files

How do I create a temporary file with a specified extension in php.
I came across [`tempnam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) but using it the extension can't be specified.

Comment: No, you can't specify an extension to `tempname()`, you will have to create your custom function for this, have a look at `User Contributed Notes` at http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might simulate `mkstemp()` (see http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp) a bit, achieving what you want to do:

```
function mkstemp( $template ) {
  $attempts = 238328; // 62 x 62 x 62
  $letters  = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  $length   = strlen($letters) - 1;

  if( mb_strlen($template) < 6 || !strstr($template, 'XXXXXX') )
    return FALSE;

  for( $count = 0; $count < $attempts; ++$count) {
    $random = "";

    for($p = 0; $p < 6; $p++) {
      $random .= $letters[mt_rand(0, $length)];
    }

    $randomFile = str_replace("XXXXXX", $random, $template);

    if( !($fd = @fopen($randomFile, "x+")) )
      continue;

    return $fd;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

So you could do:

```
if( ($f = mkstemp("test-XXXXXX.txt")) ) {
  fwrite($f, "test\n");
  fclose($f);
}
```

Answer (score 49):

Easiest way i have found is to create tempfile and then just rename it. For example:

```
 $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "Pre_");
 rename($tmpfname, $tmpfname .= '.pdf');
```

Comment: Also rename returns true for success and false for failure so that is probably pretty useful as well.

Comment: As explained in [@CrimsonNosedAnole answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69494234/1584915), there is an edge case where `tempnam()` + extension might not be unique.

Comment: @DurandA I would be shocked if that edge case ever happens. Anyway rename would return false in that scenario, so you can just check.

Answer (score 15):

my way is using [tempnam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

```
$file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'prefix');
file_put_contents($file.'.extension', $data);
{
   //use your file
}
unlink($file);//to delete an empty file that tempnam creates
unlink($file.'.extension');//to delete your file
```

Comment: Also, it would be quite useful to `unlink ($file)` not to create random trash in `/tmp`

Comment: I don't think this is safe. `tempnam()` ensures that `$file` doesn't exist. `$file . '.extension'` may as well exist.

Comment: As long as you use a sufficiently unique prefix and are consistent with its use it should be safe; `unique-prefix-[tempnam-output].extension` is only created after `unique-prefix-[tempnam-output]` is created and that file was guaranteed unique. You'll only get into trouble if you try deleting the tempnam file before you're done with your extended file.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say tempnam() gives you a file of "filename". You move it to "filename.ext". At any point, tempnam() can give you "filename" again. If you check for "filename.ext", reject the filename given by tempnam(), and call it again, you still end up with the possibility that between one step and another, a file will get created with the same name. (This is discussed in the user comments on the documentation page for tempnam(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php.)

However, if you just leave the file created by tempnam() alone (not deleting "filename" until you delete "filename.ext") and work with that filename + the extension, then there is no chance that tempnam() will use that filename again (as far as I can see). Yes, it is messy to have "filename" and "filename.ext" for every single file. On the other hand, it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this solution:

```
$uid = uniqid('', true);
$path = sys_get_temp_dir() . "some_prefix_$uid.myextension";
```

Note: I do not put the prefix in `uniqid` because, IMHO, it's not its duty

Comment: An extra `/` is required beween `sys_get_temp_dir()` and the filename (at least on my platform).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function makeTempFileInFolder($prefix, $suffix, $folder="")
{
  if (strlen($folder)==0) $folder = sys_get_temp_dir();
  do { 
    $file = $folder."/".$prefix.rand(1,99999).time().$suffix; 
  } while (file_exists($file));
  return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same as `tempnam()` except the additional parameter:

```php
function tempnamp($dir, $prefix, $postfix) {
  $maxAttempts = 1000;
  // Trim trailing slashes from $dir.
  $dir = rtrim($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
  // If we don't have permission to create a directory, fail, otherwise we will
  // be stuck in an endless loop.
  if (!is_dir($dir) || !is_writable($dir)) return false;
  // Make sure characters in prefix and postfix are safe.
  if (strpbrk($prefix, '\\/:*?"<>|') !== false) return false;
  if (strpbrk($postfix, '\\/:*?"<>|') !== false) return false;
  // Attempt to create a random file until it works.
  $attempts = 0;
  do
  {
    $path = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$prefix.mt_rand(100000, mt_getrandmax()).$postfix;
    $fp = @fopen($path, 'x+');
  } while (!$fp && $attempts++ < $maxAttempts);
  if ($fp) fclose($fp);
  return $path;
}
```

That 'p' at the end of the name stands for 'postfix'.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe using

`move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name.myextension");`

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#example-2209

Answer (score -1):

Rename does it, find the extension with pathinfo and then replace with the extension you want.

```
$tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'FOO');
$newname = str_replace(pathinfo($tmpfname, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),'pdf',$tmpfname);
rename($tmpfname, $newname);
//do what you want with $newname
unlink($newname);
```